# non-local non-linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to solve the following equation where $u:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\lambda>0$ and $\delta$ is the Dirac function:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \frac{u(y)-u(x)}{(y-x)^2} + u(x)^2 = \lambda \delta(x) $$

I tried to expand the solution in $\lambda$: 
$$u(x)=\lambda u_1(x) + \lambda^2 u_2(x) + ...$$ 
and go in Fourier space where the equation reads ($*$ denotes the convolution product):

$$-|q| u(q) + \frac{1}{2\pi}(u*u)(q) = \lambda$$.

The first order term $u_1(q)=\frac{1}{|q|}$ has not a definite Inverse fourier transform but still Mathematica yields $u_1(x) = -(2\ln(|x|+2\gamma)$, $\gamma$ being Euler constant (I don't know how though). But starting from the second order terms are divergent.

I search on the web but did not found any similar equation.

I would be thankful for any hints, new idea to try or link to similar equations

Comment: The integral $\int$ is over what? $(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes $(-\infty, +\infty)$

Comment: Is $u^2(x)$ intended to be $u(x)^2$ or $u(u(x))$? The integral is in the sense of the principal value?

Comment: $u(x)^2$. Yes for $x \neq 0$ taking the principal value makes the integral finite.

Comment: I think it's different fo $x=0$, the integral is certainly non-finite in order to account for the dirac on the other side of the equality.